# svn update of directory with muliply repositories checkouts

Tags: svn, bash

I have a development directory that contains checkouts from svn repositories that stays in non svn directories. I would like to update all of dirs being in the svns.

Dir structure is similar to one below:

[image]

How would you solve the issue?

I am came with "brute force" solution, but it is not very much intelligent:

```
for i in `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -type d | grep -v .svn`; do svn up $i; done
```

It would be nice to have sth like to have:

```
svn --recursive update development_dir.
```

Comment: i do not see anything wrong with your solution. it works, and since you are not developing a full scale svn client why bother?

Comment: Isn't it easier to have a list with the directories with different source repositories. It's not like they change that often is it? Then you could simply do `cat file_with_repositories | xargs svn up`

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, svn does not support this feature. What you can do, however, is to optimize your command by eliminating for loop and piping to grep. The command should look like this:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 3 -name "*.svn" -type d -exec svn up {}/.. \;
```

To make life easier, you can set up a Bash alias, for example:

```
alias svn_up_recursive='find . -mindepth 1 \
-maxdepth 3 -name "*.svn" -type d -exec svn up {}/.. \;'
```

... and invoke the whole script with `svn_up_recursive` command. Or create a shell script and put it into your `bin` directory. I personally prefer shell scripts as it is easier to support, extend them, process command line arguments etcetera.

Comment: i would argue that this is a no feature because check-ins are atomic operations, how would you handle check-in failures for different repositories? would you have to revert the ones that have succeeded? what if reverting fails? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about create a dummy branch/repository and set the externals to the required branches. this way svn update at the top level will do a update in all subfolders. May be you can skip the non svn dir/files.

You can also cheat svn by having a .svn/entries file in the non-svn folders, which will lie to subversion that the non-svn folder is versioned. As long as you do not change the folder names, you will also not have any problem in commits in this approach.